# Primefaces openDialogue not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton, faces-config

Prerequisites:

- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

---

User Story:

When clicking on a CommandButton, a Window should pop up.

---

Implementation:

commandbutton

```
<p:commandButton value="+"  actionListener="#{beanname.showDialogue}" />
```

bean

```
public void showDialogue() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/Dialogues/Dialogue");}
```

faces-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
<application>
   <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>

</faces-config>
```

### The popup to open is placed in src/main/webapp/Dialogues

---

Outcome:

[image: Outcome]

When Clicking on the button the URL reloads from host/applicationname/ to host/applicationname/faces/[pagewherecommandbuttonis]

---

Question:

What am i (possibly) missing here, in order to get the popup working?

Comment: Your setup seems correct, only think i can think of is a wrong url to the dialogue xhtml

Answer (score 0):

You must do this:

```
org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('widgetName').show();");
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use the dialog framework to open an external xhtml page in a dialog that is generated dynamically on runtime, not open an existing dialog inside a xhtml site.